# How can I test a static class casting with Mockito and JUnit?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I'm testing a method that returns a object type casted, but right now I'm getting a java.lang.ClassCastException.

I have tested with a mock object and with an instance object and I'm getting the same result.

In the implementation I have that Employee class extends from User class.

Method to test in class EmployeeDelegate:

```
    public Employee getEmployeeByUsername(String username){
        User user = userService.getUser(username);      
        return (Employee) user;
    }
```

Unit test:

```
    @Test
    public void testGetEmployeeByUsername() {
       User user = new User();      
       String username = "johnDoe";             
       Mockito.when(userDelegate.getUser(any(String.class))).thenReturn(user);    
       Employee response = employeeDelegate.getEmployeeByUsername(username);    
    }
```

I also tried to do

```
User user = Mockito.mock(User.class)
```

But still doesn't work

I expect the static cast works correctly.

Comment: `.thenReturn(user);` with `user` being a `User` and then you explicitly cast to `FrontOfficeEmployee`, how is that supposed to ever work, both in the test and in the production code.

Comment: Why do you have a `userService` which returns `User`s, a method that claims to return an `Employee` and actually returns an `FrontOfficeEmployee`?

Comment: I have made an update in my question, actually the method should return a (Employee) user, not a (FrontOfficeEmployee).

Answer (score 1):

A `FrontOfficeEmployee` is a `User`, but a `User` is not necessarily a `FrontOfficeEmployee`.

Your delegate should return a new instance of a `FrontOfficeEmployee` instead of a new `User`.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it doing the next thing:

I change the method implementation as following:

```
public Employee getEmployeeByUsername(String username){
    return (Employee) userService.getUser(username);                
}
```

Then, the unit test case works like this:

```
@Test
public void testGetEmployeeByUsername(){           
    String username = "daegalle";               
    Employee user = Mockito.mock(Employee.class);
    Mockito.when((Employee) userService.getUser(username)).thenReturn(user);    

    Employee response = employeeDelegate.getEmployeeByUsername(username);  

    Assert.assertEquals(user, response);
}
```